# Why it's not working when I try to parse the data in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am uploading excel file using ajax and then from there receiving the state and the reason of the failure from the upload page to the PHP page ajax function using `json_encode` but am not able to access the data each one where as the alert of the data is showing perfectly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#excel_file').change(function() {
    $('#export_excel').submit();
  });
  $('#export_excel').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "excelupload.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data, status) {
        alert(data); //
        var datas = JSON.parse(data); // not working
        $('#result').html(datas.a); //not woking
        $('#reason').html(datas.b);
        $('#excel_file').val('');

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<tr style="background-color:#666;">
  <td style="color:#FFF;">
    <div id="result" style="color:red;"> </div>
  </td>
  <td style="color:#FFF;">
    <div id="reason" style="color:red;"> </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php            
$insertTable= mysql_query("INSERT INTO `rt_state_mst`( `OLE_STATE_NAME`, `OLE_COUNT_ID`) VALUES ( '$state' , '$country_result[0]');");

echo json_encode(array("a" => $state, "b" => "Record has been added"));
?>
```

Comment: What's with the markup before the `<?php ... ?>` block?

Comment: "the alert of the data is showing perfectly". What is it? What does it show?

Comment: {"a":"Uttar Pradesh","b":"Record Already added"}{"a":"Jammu","b":"Record Already added"}{"a":"sadas","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"dsad","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"as","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"d","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"dasd","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"dsd","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"asd","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"d","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"as","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"}{"a":"as","b":"COUNTRY NOT FOUND"} it shows this in alert

Comment: This doesn't seems to be proper json data

Comment: If possible could you post the whole `excelupload.php` file code?

Answer (score 0):

`excelupload.php` should contain only php content. And if you want to return `json_encode` data from  `excelupload.php` then use the below property in your ajax code.

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: when i add dataType: "json", below url the ajax stops working

Comment: and when i remove dataType: "json", in console it is showing this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 49 of the JSON data

Comment: Have you debugged the code, before echoing json data, insert query is working? And Is `$state` an array?